# Trying to display a list into a list view using and API

Tags: c#, android, api, xamarin

The page is simply a list view and all it has to do is return the items in this case a list of surveys to the `listview` to display. Have used the exact same code for a message inbox, to do the same thing except return the list of messages. but this one doesn't seem to work, I have limited knowledge and therefore do not understand the error or where to even look

When I load the page, I get this error:

> Java.Lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>         at java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object
>   reference
>         at at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:409)
>         at at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
>         at at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2363)
>         at at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1970)
>         at at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:704)
>         at at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:765)
>         at at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1744)
>         at at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2162)
>         at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>         at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>         at at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>         at at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>         at at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>         at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>         at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>         at at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>         at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>         at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>         at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>         at at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
>         at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>         at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>         at at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>         at at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>         at at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:726)
>         at at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17637)
>         at at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5575)
>         at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2346)
>         at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2068)
>         at at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
>         at at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6337)
>         at at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:874)
>         at at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:686)
>         at at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:621)
>         at at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:860)
>         at at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>         at at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>         at at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>         at at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>         at at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>         at at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

This is the code for the page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Dribl.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "Surveys", Theme = "@style/CustomActionBarTheme")]
    public class Surveys : Activity
    {
        LinearLayout surveysBtn;
        LinearLayout availabilityBtn;
        LinearLayout inboxBtn;
        LinearLayout dashboardBtn;

        Button backBtn;

        private List <String> surveys;
        private ListView surveyListview;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Surveys);
            //add the action bar to the layout 
            ActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.action_bar);
            ActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

            //action bar nav
            surveysBtn = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.SurveyLayout);
            surveysBtn.Click += surveyBtn_Click;
            inboxBtn = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.InboxLayout);
            inboxBtn.Click += InboxBtn_Click;
            availabilityBtn = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.availabilityLayout);
            availabilityBtn.Click += availabilityBtn_Click;
            dashboardBtn = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.dashboardLayout);
            dashboardBtn.Click += availabilityBtn_Click;


            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            System.Uri uri = new System.Uri("http://dribl.com/api/getAllMySurveys");
            NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();


            parameters.Add("token", GlobalVariables.token);

            client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);
            client.UploadValuesCompleted += client_UploadValuesCompleted;
        }


        void client_UploadValuesCompleted(object sender, UploadValuesCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            string json = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.Result);
            List<Survey> survey = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Survey>>(json);

            //display the retrieved msg in the console output
            //Console.WriteLine(message[1].message + " is the message");

            //display the msg in a text view at top of page
            //txt.Text = message[1].message;


            //get the list view create a string to store and add to the list view based on the json return
            surveyListview = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.surveyListView);
            surveys = new List<string>();

            for (int c = 0; c < survey.Count; c++)
            {
                surveys.Add(survey[c].survey);

            }

            //Msgs.Add(message[1].message);
            //Msgs.Add(message[0].message);

            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, surveys);

            surveyListview.Adapter = adapter;


        }

        void surveyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Surveys));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();
        }

        void dashboardBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(dashboard));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();
        }

        void availabilityBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Availability));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();
        }

        void InboxBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(MsgInbox));
            this.StartActivity(intent);
            this.Finish();
        }


    }

    public class Survey
    {
        public string survey { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you checked `List<string> surveys` contains values or not?

Comment: items are added to surveys from the API call. see the loop

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the items in your ArrayList is null. That's why it is giving NullPointerException when you scroll down to that item. It would be better if you check if any item is null before adding it to ListView.

```
for (int c = 0; c < survey.Count; c++)
{
if(survey[c].survey != null)           
surveys.Add(survey[c].survey);
}
```